# Magento data migration 1.9 to 2.3 Integrity Check failed error

Tags: error, data-migration, magento1.9.2.3, magento2.3.3, wamp

After successfully completed migrate:settings,

> php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset
>   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.3/config.xml

getting error while running migrate:data,

> php bin/magento migrate:data --reset
>   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.3/config.xml

[image]

How to solve the error?

Comment: Please check /var/migration.log file and let me know your detail issue. Also, remove or ignore any third party module's table if present.

Comment: @Sumit Here is my log -> https://paste.ofcode.org/pCwKQY6dEPcB9vJjyJkEEj  any help?

Comment: Issue is with the data mapping in your map.xml

Comment: @Sumit What i need to do?

Comment: remove or ignore any third party module's table if present

Comment: Remove is not possible because i need my module in magento 2 also. How to manage this situation?

Comment: You can take a backup of those tables and then remove them.

Comment: okay, let me try

Comment: shall i try this instead or remove https://oyenetwork.com/articles/data-migration-to-magento2-case-study/

Comment: Yes Zus, you can try this solution for your issue.

Comment: if you run with max verbose it will tell you more closely where it is unhappy - step and often the exact line or index

Comment: a further note to this - if it really fails at the inventory step, I would recommend just taking this step out of the migration both data and delta - it's unnecessary until you go live and then it is much easier to just import the inventory, as there is an import that works.
If you're going to run delta, it's worth also skipping the rewrites, a cause of errors on changes esp if category/product rewrites exist.
Products, clients and orders are the ones you want to migrate using the tool

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that you're missing some other errors that happened earlier.

The `Inventory Step` is the last step in the `integrity check` stage and the migration tool runs all steps in the integrity check stage, even if one of them throws an exception. Problems occurring anywhere during the `integrity check` stage get reported at the end of it, not the step at which they occur.

If you look at at \Migration\Mode\Data::runIntegrity, you can see it has a foreach loop, which runs all steps in the integrity check stage, but it only checks if these steps completed successfully after the loop and throws the `Integrity Check Failed` exception if any one of the steps failed.

Chances are that you'll have red errors further up the output. As suggested in the comments above you need to carefully review your `/var/migration.log` file to find out what step in the integrity check is actually failing and why.